# Is it possible to take an array of values of hidden field in mvc controller?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I used the below code to set an array of values to hidden field in jquery:

```
$('#savephoto').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var idArray = [];
        var i = 0;
        $(".album_photo .buttonClicked").each(function () {          
            idArray [i++] = $(this).data('assigned-id');         
        });
        $("#selPhoto").val(idArray);
        $("#photoForm").submit();
});
```

and the hidden field in the form is declared as   `@Html.Hidden("selPhoto");` in the 'photoForm' form and the controller I declared as below:

```
public ActionResult selectFromAlbum(int[] selPhoto)
    But I get a null value at 'selPhoto'.
```

Anybody know the answer,Please help.

Comment: Hidden fields are posted back to the server (as long as they are in the form tags), unless they are disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually passing array

Should be this

```
public ActionResult selectFromAlbum(string selPhoto)
```

Comment: @Neethu : replace `string selPhoto` with `FormCollection collection` and see what you get in `collection`

Comment: Sorry Dark Knight, It was cache,solution public ActionResult selectFromAlbum(string selPhoto) is working fine .thanks!!